# How do I access an NSMutableDictionary's property inside an array using fast enum?

Tags: ios, for-loop, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, fast-enumeration

I have a "bookshelf" array that contains four NSMutableDictionary "book" (which contains three properties), my question is how do I access the hasBeenRead flag/property of the "book" dictionary to find out which book has not been read?

Book(s):

```
 {
     "title":"Winnie-the-Pooh",
     "author":"A.A. Milne"
     "hasBeenRead": No
 }
```

Bookshelf:

```
[
    {
         "title":"Jungle Book",
         "author":"Rudyard Kipling",
         "hasBeenRead":"Yes"
    },
    {
         "title":"Winnie-the-Pooh",
         "author":"A.A. Milne",
         "hasBeenRead":"No"
    },
    {
         "title":"Alice In Wonderland",
         "author":"Lewis Carroll",
         "hasBeenRead":"Yes"
    }
]
```

I can get the Book NSMutableDictionary:

```
for (NSString* readBook in self.bookshelf) {
    NSLog(@"Books: %@", readBook);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is `readBook` really a string? Try logging its `class`.

Comment: In other words, "How do I use NSArray and NSDictionary?"  Two objects that anyone programming in Objective-C should be intimately familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for (NSDictionary* readBook in self.bookshelf) {
  NSLog(@"Books: %@", [readBook objectForKey:@"hasBeenRead"]);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can filter your bookshelf use `NSPredicate`

```
NSString *hasBeenReadFlag = @"No";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.hasBeeRead == %@", hasBeenReadFlag];
NSArray *filtered = [self.bookshelf filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@", filtered);
```

now you can get all book has not been read

Regards

[Read more](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html)